# Understand chef cookbook with a book

Tags: chef-infra

I have started using chef few weeks back, now i am able to write recipes on my own, but these recipes does not have the standard and very basic recipes.I want to do more with these , is there any book available on chef and chef cookbook so i can understand the recipes better.

Comment: Such questions (searching for off-site resource) are against the rules of StackOverflow. Wether this rule is useful or not - have you gone the easy path and searched your favorite book store?

Comment: there is different books, don't know which to choose

Comment: Such book stores have recession systems for that problem.